# Spatial joining one to many within distance using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join, arcgis-10.5, one-to-many

I have two datasets, the dataset A contains the main information, I want to join all the points from dataset A to all the points in dataset B within 150 meters.

From dataset B I need to keep two variables (id, category). I also need to know for each point A how many points B are joined.

I tried with **buffer and spatial join with ArcGIS (ArcMap 10.5)** but it failed.

I created a buffer around the dataset A, and then I did a spatial joint with the feature **"intersect"**, the option **"keep all target features",** got an

> "ERROR 000426: Out of Memory" and "Failed to execute (SpatialJoin)

I also did a spatial join with the feature **"within a distance"**, the option **"keep all target features"**, got an

> "ERROR 000426: Out of Memory" and "Failed to execute (SpatialJoin)

I also tried without the option **"keep all target features"** and by subsetting my database, and I got the same error message.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please  [edit] the question to include the GIS software you are using (including version).

Comment: Please edit the question to specify *how* you tried a buffer and spatial join and *how* it failed (exact error message or behavior)

Comment: Are you using an enterprise geodb (e.g. SQL Server)?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall where can I check this information?

Comment: Are your datasets in what used to be called "sde" (now referred to as Enterprise Geodatabase)? or are they in a file geodb (.gdb)? shapefiles? personal geodb (.mdb)?